# Scala: if-else to declarative code with Option

Tags: scala

I have a piece of scala code as(x contains several Option fields):

```
x.y.flatMap(_.z).map {
        z =>
          someMethod(z) // for side effect
      }.getOrElse {
        if (condition) {
          someOtherMethod() // for side effect
        } else {
          yetAntherMethod // for side effect
        }
      }
```

Basically code executes different paths based on certain conditions, like conventional if-else in imperative java code.

I want to modify it to make it more declarative, like executing different paths based on certain fields in x. Pseudo code like this:

```
x.a defined then do A 
   otherwise x.b defined then do B 
       otherwise x.c defined do C..and so on
```

I am not able to compose the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the answer from @ccheneson, you can also use a destructuring pattern match:

```
case class MyStruc(a: Option[String], b: Option[String], c: Option[String])
def doA(a: String): Unit = println(s"A: $a")
def doB(b: String): Unit = println(s"B: $b")
def doC(c: String): Unit = println(s"C: $c")

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  def doIt(x: MyStruc) = {
    x match {
      case MyStruc(Some(a), _, _) => doA(a)
      case MyStruc(_, Some(b), _) => doB(b)
      case MyStruc(_, _, Some(c)) => doC(c)
      case _ => ()
    }
  }

  doIt(MyStruc(Some("1"), Some("2"), Some("3"))) // A: 1
  doIt(MyStruc(None, Some("4"), Some("5")))      // B: 4
  doIt(MyStruc(None, None, Some("6")))           // C: 6
  doIt(MyStruc(None, None, None))                // no output
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could compose the flow in the following way

```
val optionalValue = Option(1)

optionalValue match {
  case Some(value) if value == 1 => A()
  case Some(value) if value == 2 => B()
  case Some(value) if value == 3 => C()
  case None =>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your class seems to have several `Option`s and to follow your pseudo code, you can use pattern matching like

```
case class MyStruc(a: Option[String], b: Option[String], c: Option[String])

val x = MyStruc(Some("1"), Some("2"), Some("3"))
x match {
  case x.a if x.a.isDefined => doA(x.a.get) 
  case x.b if x.b.isDefined => doB(x.b.get)
  case x.c if x.c.isDefined => doA(x.c.get)
}
```

You can use `isDefined` to check if it is a `Some` and if it is, it is safe to call `.get` on it.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution for the specific example in the question is to just use `if/else`:

```
if (x.y.flatMap(_.z).map(someMethod).isEmpty) {
  if (condition) {
    someOtherMethod()
  } else {
    yetAntherMethod()
  }
}
```

The more general case of chaining `Option` values can be done with `orElse`:

```
x.a.map(A) orElse
  x.b.map(B) orElse 
  x.c.map(C)
```

You can use `Option.when` to turn a condition into an `Option` if necessary.